# Enum with functions in C

Tags: c

While I examine the source code of ffmpeg, I see this line:

```
enum AVDurationEstimationMethod av_fmt_ctx_get_duration_estimation_method
(const AVFormatContext* ctx);
```

What is the functionality of `enum` here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`av_fmt_ctx_get_duration_estimation_method` is a function which returns an object of enum type `AVDurationEstimationMethod` .

Comment: Te be a bit pedantic, it returns an object of type `enum AVDurationEstimationMethod`

Answer (score 5):

`enum AVDurationEstimationMethod` together is a type which the function `av_fmt_ctx_get_duration_estimation_method` returns

The keyword `enum`, like `struct` and `union`, is necessary to represent the type. To omit it, use `typedef`:

```
typedef enum AVDurationEstimationMethod sometype;
```

Then you can use it like:

```
sometype av_fmt_ctx_get_duration_estimation_method(const AVFormatContext* ctx);
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is a declaration of a function which returns an instance of `enum AVDurationEstimationMethod` which is an enumeration type.

Answer (score 3):

In C enums effectivly live in their own 'namespace' (this is also the case for structs). To make it clear that you're specify an enum type you must prefix it with the `enum` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Here the function `av_fmt_ctx_get_duration_estimation_method();` is taking `const AVFormatContext* ctx` as argument and returning `enum AVDurationEstimationMethod`

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavformat_2options_8c.html#ac7070b68d7ca5fd577f9f835556ebeff) you can find about the method, and [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avformat_8h.html#a7c2692ffa20d3e888e40e79eeda6d73b) about the enum return type